# SPWeb.EnsureUser has limitations?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, fba

We're converting all SP permissions into ActiveDirectory groups (one per uninherited object, per role level). I wanted the group names to reflect where the permissions were/are, so I assigned each group with a name that matched the site structure:

`sitecollection|site|list|Full Control`

Active Directory had issues with the pipes and the potential length, so I reconfigured everything to use the description of the Active Directory object instead. The actual CN of the group is `-someNumber-` (-1-,-2-, etc).

I ran across an interesting phenomena while adding the groups into SharePoint under the same role level; I had to start the groups at 1000 else the EnsureUser couldn't find the group no matter what.

`$web.EnsureUser('c:0-.f|myprovider|-1-')` says it doesn't exist, whereas `$web.EnsureUser('c:0-.f|myprovider|-1000-')` does just fine.

Is there some sort of limitation to the number of characters a SAM Account Name / Principal Name must be when being searched by SharePoint?

Answer (score -2):

You need to include the Domain name in EnsureUser - Domain\Username

Or you can just add i:0#.f|myprovider| to the username so it looks like i:0#.f|myprovider|myuser and pass the result into EnsureUser. In my case "myprovider" is the name of my custom membership provider.

Comment: We're moving all of our permissions to ActiveDirectory - completely separate from SharePoint (since SP groups can't cross site collections). So, we can't use the user qualified name since we're not adding individual users. And `c:0-.f|myprovider|-1000-` works fine, so I'm not sure it's an issue with the format that I'm passing in.